# Remove bottom border from table

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to remove the bottom border on the table on [this page](http://bdgie.co/about/friends/).

I added this to the css on my child theme...

```
/* Remove Border from Bottom of Table */
.noborder table{border-collapse: separate !important; }
```

Also made the table have the correct class.

Yet it still grabs the css from the twitter bootstrap.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just: `.noborder tr { border:none; }`

Comment: Nice! So quick I have to wait to accept the answer:)

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS file, use

```
tr { border-bottom: none !important; }
```

Or if you don't want to remove the bottom border from each `tr` tag, place a class on that one and then target the class instead of `tr`.